# Line breaks not transferred from DESCRIPTION via \packageDESCRIPTION{}

Tags: r, r-package

The Description field in my DESCRIPTION file contains several lines. In the documentation file mypackage.Rd there are the lines

```
The DESCRIPTION file:
\packageDESCRIPTION{mypackage}
```

The macro `\packageDESCRIPTION` copies information from the DESCRIPTION file to the manual of the package. The result looks like that:

```
Package: mypackage
Type: Package
...
Description: Only one too long line which goes over the right border of the pdf
License: GPL-3  
...
```

Building the package works. Problem: In the pdf version of the manual the line breaks of the DESCRIPTION file are not transferred from the \packageDESCRIPTION macro. The entry above contains only one line which (because there is too much text for one line) goes far above the right boundary of the pdf. In the HTML-version of the manual which can be seen in RStudio, the manual looks ok, the Description field contains the complete content of the DESCRIPTION file and the content goes over several lines. 
Is there a solution for that or is the only way either to reduce the length of the Description field in the DESCRIPTION file or not to use the macro \packageDESCRIPTION?

Comment: that macro is defined as `\newcommand{\packageDESCRIPTION}{\Sexpr[results=rd,stage=build]{tools:::Rd_package_DESCRIPTION("#1")}}` and if you look at the source for `tools:::Rd_package_DESCRIPTION` I don't see any way for it to embed `\cr`'s. I'd post this to one of the R mailing lists or submit a bug report to R core.

Comment: I uploaded today an R package (RMixpanel). The issue still persists.